# Boost and Nixysa

Tags: google-chrome, boost, boost-asio, npapi, scons

I'm writing a NPAPI plugins using [Nixysa](http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/). I want to use Boost. For some reason, I don't succeed to include it.

What I have tried so far: I have installed the Boost library through my package manager (Ubuntu), and then included it, like this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

When I do that, the code compiles successfully, but the plugin just not loading in the browser. No errors.

How can I fix that?

If there's any better way to include Boost, I'd happy to hear it. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you do whats said in here: Getting started in Windows (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your plugin loading successfully if you don't include any boost header ?
One of the causes of plugins not loading is that they have undefined symbols or missing dependent libraries. You can check that with ldd -r -d /path/to/libyourplugin.so

Comment: Agreed; this seems like the most likely answer.  If you're on Windows you can use Dependency Walker.  Boost is probably dynamically linking to the libraries that ASIO requires, which then can't be found by the browser. Dependency walker on Windows, ldd on mac/linux can help you verify this.